# sub menu within a menu

Tags: android, menu

I am trying to display a menu item named "share" by clicking the menu button.
now i need to create a submenu item for this share menu item.
The sub menu item should be visible when the share menu item is clicked alternatively (when clicked first time becomes visible next time invisible and so on.).
I found few solutions which are displaying the sub menuitems but those are being displayed along with the menu item.

This is my code for creating menus

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu m) {

    m.add(1,1,0,"one").setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    m.add(1,2,0,"two").setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    m.add(1,3,0,"three").setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    m.add(1,4,0,"four").setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    m.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
    m.getItem(1).setVisible(false);
    return true;
}
```

and my onPrepareOptionsMenu()

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu m) {
    if(isvisible)
    {
    isvisible = false;
     m.getItem(0).setVisible(true);

    m.getItem(1).setVisible(true);


}
else{
    isvisible = true;
    m.getItem(0).setVisible(false);

    m.getItem(1).setVisible(false);

}


    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(m);

}
```

I need the remaining two items to be shown when i click on the menu item rather than on the menu button.
Can anyone suggest me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override the below method:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**The above method is called every time before the menu is shown.**

```
Here you can maintain a bool and hide the submenu depending upon the condition of your check.
```

**EDIT:**

By default `set bool to false` and `on false show the menu and set the bool to true` and on next call check this bool and if it is true, set it false and make the menu invisible.use this line to make the menu visible or invisible:

`menu.getItem(index).getSubMenu().getItem(index).setVisible(true);`
Store the bool in `sharedpreference`.

Comment: When the menu button in the emulator is clicked , by default the menu item gets disappeared.
Can you give some more information on how to make the submenu items of the menuitem "share" to be invisible when the menu item is clicked alternatively

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am using this code to add menu items to my application
menu.add(0, 0, 0, "New Game");    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Quit");
Now if i use menu.getItem(0).setVisible(false); the first menu items gets invisible which is not the one i require.
Please suggest me further

Comment: Thanks for the support. As you suggested i used the visibility concept (without the submenu()) with having four menu items with two invisible intially.
the code's working fine when i click the menu button in the emulator. But what i need is when i click the " menu item " i need the other two menuitems to be visible.
Can you please suggest some more information please.

Comment: I tried to do it by using the same in onOptionsItemSelected() but as it is the function that is called when item is clicked i understood that it wont solve my problem.Plz suggest

Comment: Even though this is not that i am intersted to do am accepting this as i am not getting responses from others because i am having less acceptance %